# Unrecognized token '&' in Fixed Fortran continuation lines

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, fortran, intel-fortran

I am editing an old project that uses **fixed form** Fortran and compiling with **IVF compiler**.  The current issue I have is with **continuation lines** in a list:

```
format(//,  10x,'*******************************************',/, &
     10x,'* DIAGONALS OF THE RESIDUAL COV. MATRIX   *',/,  &
     10x,'*******************************************',//,  &
     2x,'MEASUREMENT',7X,'  RESIDUAL COVARIANCE', /)
```

For some reason, the ampersand is not working for me and I keep getting the error:

> unrecognized token '&' skipped

For smaller lines, increasing the fixed form line length and making the two lines one worked but there are instances where the lines are too large for this. The code was written around 15 years ago and in fixed form Fortran but I am unfamiliar with Fortran and how the new compiler and settings affect the code.

Converting to free form causes a series of errors with other formatting and the code does not seem broken so I do not think converting to free form is necessary. I have tried other methods of indenting, such as an **ampersand** at the end of a line and at the beginning of next, an **asterisk**, and a **slash** that other forums suggested using and they produce the error:

> error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one
> of: <HOLLERITH_CONSTANT> <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM>
> <CHARACTER_CONSTANT> ) ...

Is there some sort of formatting I am missing or is there any settings I could edit to fix these errors?

Comment: That isn't how fixed source form works.  Can you point to why you think that is how to continue lines in fixed form, so that we can correct it?

Comment: Hello, sorry I thought this must have built in fixed fortran and this is how the code that worked about 15 years ago was. If not then this could possibly be free form and I was mistaken.

Comment: You can normally guess which form it is from the file name, namely from the extension.

Comment: It is a .f file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fixed form Fortran, you continue a line with any character in column 6 of the next line, not an & at the end of the 1st line. Try:

```
      format(//,  10x,'*******************************************',/,
     c  10x,'* DIAGONALS OF THE RESIDUAL COV. MATRIX   *',/,
     c  10x,'*******************************************',//,
     c  2x,'MEASUREMENT',7X,'  RESIDUAL COVARIANCE', /)
```

Comment: Hello Dan, this seems to clear all of the errors. However, I still do not know why the original code, that supposedly worked about 15 years ago on CVF compiler, had the ampersands at the end of the lines. Do you know if & used to be used for continuation lines?

Comment: @GavinChandler Are you sure then that it was fixed format? Did the file end with .f? If it did, most likely it was compiled with a flag to use free-format. I do not know of Intel's compiler flag for that but I know gfortran's flag was -ffree-form. Old trick, don't know if it still works. Put an & in column 73 of the 1st line (fixed form only recognizes the first 72 characters) and an & in column 6 of the continuing line. This is supposed to work compiled as fixed form and free form.

Comment: The file did end with a .f but the project has .f and .for files and most files compile without errors in fixed form but not free form. There were only about 6 scripts that had errors with &s in the code. Also the program defaults were for fixed form. As for adding the & to the 73 and the first line, I get the error:   **error #5118: First statement in file must not be continued**

Comment: Note that using `c` as the continuation character could be confusing for some people scanning through the code since it is commonly used as a comment symbol.  I think using `&` would make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Or use the compiler switch -free with .for or .f

Or use the compiler switch -fixed -132 with a .F90 .

In your case I would preserve the .f and cp that to .F90 and then explicitly have the makefile compile the .F90 ...

I normally use -fixed -132 with a .F90 as I often have -d-lines that I retain in the code, and I could not get -d-lines. To work with -free.

Comment: It seems that the error was corrected when I added the a character to the 6th column on the next line. Do you think it would still be necessary or worth while to do this?

Comment: Knowing that it would have worked is important. You could have changed the suffix, which suggests -free, or explicitly state -free, or make the code explicitly conform to -fixed. You did the later which is fine. Doing -fixed with .F90 is somewhat non-ordinary, but seemed worth mentioning. The fact it works now is usually hard to argue against.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Holmz. I may try your method if other issues arise but at the moment conforming to -fixed seems to work.